# WatchOS 2 (beta 5): watchAppInstalled returns false

Tags: ios, apple-watch, ios9, xcode7, watchos-2

The Watch App is installed on the watch and I can tap and run it on the Watch, but `watchAppInstalled` method returns false.

Also, I can only install the Watch App using Xcode 7.  If I try to install the Watch App using the Watch iOS app (from Apple) by turning on the switch, the Watch App gets deleted right after the installation completes.

**Update:**
This bug is fixed in Xcode 7 beta 6

Comment: I have had the same behavior and it has been fixed for me only after watch reset and setup from scratch.

Comment: did you add `arm64` architecture  in valid architectures for both Extention and WatchApp. I have faced same kind of issue an resolved adding `arm64` in valid architectures.

Comment: @Zubair: Brilliant!  This is the right answer and fixed the problem.  Please add this as an answer so that I can accept it and you get the bounty.  you need to do it today before the bounty expires.

Comment: Updating to Xcode 7 beta 6 solved the issue for me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What worked for me was adding the `arm64` architecture to both the Watch app and iOS app as @Zubair suggested.

**Update:**
This bug is fixed in Xcode 7, beta 6

Answer (score 5):

[Apple Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/WatchConnectivity/Reference/WCSession_class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/WCSession/watchAppInstalled) says:

> The session must be configured and activated before accessing this
>   property.

So, you should [configure and activate](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/WatchConnectivity/Reference/WCSession_class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/WCSession/activateSession) the session before using this property.

Comment: Yes, of course the session has been configured and activated. It actually works fine on the simulator (which confirms that the session has been configured and activated properly).

Comment: I was wondering why connectivity stopped working. I was due to my call to `activate` getting removed in a bad merge. Thanks for this!

Answer (score 4):

I had same issue.

I just add WatchConnectivity.framework to my main app target and watch extension target. And it works now.

Hope i helped.

Cheers.

Update: i read comments above and check my architecture: already had arm64

Answer (score 0):

It now works for me, what I did:

Reset and Re-coupled the Apple Watch and added a Passcode to it (what I never did before).

Edit: You can then safely disable the Passcode and it will still work.