# WatchConnectivity connection in iPhone -> Watch direction

Tags: ios, watchkit, ios9

I'm trying to make WCSession (Xcode 7.0 beta 5) work in the Phone -> Watch direction on real devices (in a simulator it works perfectly) but every time get an error:

> Error: "Domain=WCErrorDomain Code=7006 Watch app is not installed".

I mean everything works in the Watch -> Phone direction (sendMessage:, updateApplicationContext:, CoreLocation, etc.). In order to exclude code-related problems I'm using the Apple's Potloc application for tests.

It seems I've tried everything and here's a full list:

1. Paired/Unpaired Watch.
2. Rebooted iPhone/Watch.
3. Reset Watch.
4. Reset iPhone (reset all settings).
5. Reinstalled iPhone/Watch applications a bunch of times.
6. Switched on/off "Show App on Apple Watch" in "My Watch" application on iPhone.

The only way iPhone is able to communicate with Watch is to answer using a callback in WCSession methods.

What else can I do?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

As expected the problem has been solved in Xcode 7.0 beta6. A project just has been rebuilt without any additional configuration and then the item #6  from my aforementioned list has solved the problem:

> 6. Switched on/off "Show App on Apple Watch" in "My Watch" application on iPhone.

Answer (score 1):

This seems similar to this:
[WatchOS 2 (beta 5): watchAppInstalled returns false](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31908445/watchos-2-beta-5-watchappinstalled-returns-false/32136216#32136216)

Did you watch out for "isWatchAppInstalled"? If yes, did it say YES or NO?

Maybe the other solutions mentioned over there work for you?

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment).

Comment: If Dmitry can find a solution to his problem in the Linked question how could that not be helpful?

Comment: Welcome to SO!  That's an auto-comment from the VLQ review queue.  Usually it's considered best practice is to mark as duplicate to link this question to that one.  Other than the link you provided, you're asking OP questions, which usually means you're looking for more info and cannot provide a complete answer; therefore it should be a comment.  I realize that you don't have enough rep to comment yet, so in that case just flag duplicate to link it and then move on.

Comment: @appleitung any manipulations in beta5 have made no effect unfortunately